# Jupyter Notebooks System Cannot Find File Specified

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I moved around my jupyter notebook virtual environment and now am facing an issue which is preventing me from launching Jupyter.  When I launch it, I get the following error.

How can I fix this? I tried reinstalling my virtual environment, but to no avail, problem persists. Interestingly, the Start file is not where my virtual environment is...

```
Start : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the 
file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start "file:///mnt/c/Users/nlandman/Projects/.local/share/jupyter/run ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo           : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```